# trace 10046 and OEM privileges

Tags: oracle, trace, privileges, oracle-enterprise-manager

It would be great if someone would share

trace 10046 privileges

and

Oracle enterprise manager (OEM) privileges

so I can ask my DBA to grant the privileges to my role, and by OEM privileges I mean is I can change the threshold on GUI environment. I have read somewhere you need operator's privileges. But correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most DBA's wont be granting system trace privs to non-DBA's, especially if this is a production system, since this involves both superuser privileges and access to the trace files that are generated.  In my shops we would never let developers have shell access to any server higher than a dev box.

If you need to generate traces, work with your DBA team.  That's their job.

Comment: thanks for the answer but our DbA's are outsourced and sit somewhere offshore we have collectively come to the conclusion that I can have these privileges only on development database.